# How to show "symbols" for bash script in VScode?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, gui, symbols, vscode-extensions

In the following screenshot we can see that the outline tab for a bash script is empty, as it does not shows any symbols. Do I need to enable any extension for this? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Bash IDE extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mads-hartmann.bash-ide-vscode). This provided a code outline in the Outline view.